# Space on footer

Tags: css, footer

I've been working on a footer for a blog. The footer generates a border around it, and I don't know what has triggered it.

What could have triggered it? 
Have a look at the website here: [http://blog.sayhi.dk](http://blog.sayhi.dk/)

```
 #footer {
    width:900px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:200px;
}

  #footerstyle {
    background-image: url(images/bbg.png);
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:20px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: I see no border, but i do see an implicit margin on the body element.

Comment: which browser are you using? I am using Chrome and see no border.

Comment: Where isthe border? I can't recognize a border on your blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your body has a margin.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I'd recommend to use a CSS reset file like [YUI Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/) to remove such oddities and inconsistencies between different browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply! The margin set to zero helped it, but the YUI Reset inflicted with my other reset. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what if you add

```
    body, html{
    padding:0;
margin:0;
    }
```

It seems this white space around your footer is from the distance between the body and the html element...